# Writing Comments table in database

Tags: database, database-design

I'm working on a social networking system that will have comments coming from several different locations.  One could be friends, one could be events, one could be groups--much like Facebook.  What I'm wondering is, from a practical standpoint, what would be the simplest way to write a comments table?  Should I do it all in one table and allow foreign keys to all sorts of different tables, or should each distinct table have its own comment table?  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single comments table is the more elegant design, I think.  Rather than multiple FKs though, consider an intermediate table - CommentedItem.  So Friend, Event, Group, etc all have FKs to CommentedItem, and you create a CommentedItem row for each new row in each of those tables. Now Comments only needs one FK, to CommentedItem.  For example, to get all Comments for a given Friend:

```
SELECT * FROM Comment c
JOIN CommentedItem ci on c.CommentedItemId = ci.CommentedItemId
JOIN Friend f on f.CommentedItemId = ci.CommentedItemId
WHERE f.FriendId = @FriendId
```

Comment: Thanks.  That sounds like a good idea, but I'm curious as to why you'd use an intermediate table if you could just do it directly?  Is it for performance issues?

Comment: Because if you don't use the intermediate table, you need a separate "FK" column for each potential commentable-item table. This allows a very awkward situation where you can have 1 comment attached to multiple different items of different types, if the DB were to get corrupted.

Comment: @Matt: Still feel we can do well without the intermediate table. We are having a column in comments table which should suffice and keep ids from the commentable-item table.

Comment: Ah, Matt, I see what you're saying.  That makes a lot of sense.  Would you still run into the same situation, though, if you were to have a commenteditems table with multiple possibilities?  How could you isolate the comment type?

Comment: I know it is an old question/answer but I don't see the solution here, you cannot have FKs into Friend/Event/Group... because you don't know in advance number of comments and if you place the FK in the intermediate table, then you are moving the problem there since you don't know the kind of item and you would need as many FK as possible commentable items. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I've done both and the answer depends on the situation. For what *you* are trying to do, I would do a SINGLE "Comments" table, and then seperate "linker" tables. This will give you the best performance as you can achieve the "[Perfect Index](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Understanding_SQL_Many_to_Many_Relationships.aspx)".

I would also recommend putting a "CommentTypeID" field in the Comments table to give a 'clue' as to which linker table you will pull from for the aditional detail.

EDIT: The CommentTypeID field should not be used in the indexes, but rather it's only for use in code.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  So would it be best to have a "Comment_Types" table that listed "Friend", "Event", "Group", etc.?  Then make that a foreign key to the Comments table?

Answer (score 0):

This is an equivalent question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307748/news-feed-database-design-as-in-facebook).

EDIT: Based on a comment, it isn't clear that this is an equivalent question, so I spell it out below.

Both questions ask about projects (both happen to be Social Networks, but that's just coincidence) where there is a question about the performance of the database. Both have a diverse set of objects that share a common collection of attributes (in one it is Events, that occur on each object, in the other it is Comments that occur on each object).

Both questions effectively ask whether it is more efficient to create a UNION query that combines the disparate common features, or to factor them out into a common table, with appropriate foreign keys.

I see them as equivalent; the best answer to one will apply equally to the other.

(If you disagree, I am happy to hear why; please leave a comment.)

Comment: I disagree with Mark, but I appreciate that rather than just reassert my position, I needed to clarify my reasons. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

one thing to be careful about is if you don't do a highly normalized database it can sometimes cause IO row chaining and table scans.

I believe oracle suggests performing a normalization model of about 3rd Normal form.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for [polymorphic associations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphic_association). Many modern web development frameworks support it out of the box, which makes it really the simplest and most painless way to handle these kind of relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can probably go to http://www.zazazine.com and look through their articles. You may find an answer there