# Assistance Learning how to add this to Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following model: (goal is to create a news feed / activity feed for my app).

Activity:

```
id.int | user_id.int | item_type.string | item_id.id | created.timestamp | data.string
```

With the intent that I can create records like:

```
{id:1, userId:1, item_type:Photo, item_id:33, time:2008-10-15 12:00:00, data:{photoName:A trip to the beach}}

{id:2, userId:1, item_type:Comment, item_id:312, time:2008-10-15 12:00:00, data:{photo_id:3131, photoName:A trip to the beach}}
```

where:

- id = auto incremement
- userid = user who created the activity
- item_type: model so this works for unlimited models in the app
- item_id: ID for the type above
- time - very important!
- data - misc info that will allow for displaying the activity without extra DB queries or joins... performance reasons...

I need you thoughts around:

1. Feedback on the model. Any concerns or improvements?
2. Now that we have a model, what is the smart way to CREATE ACTIVITIES for several of the items on the App, like Books (Create, Update, Commented), Photos (Create, Commented)

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing a News Feed / Activity Feed on Several Models - Recommendations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809430/implementing-a-news-feed-activity-feed-on-several-models-recommendations)

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable source of information for activity streams/feeds seems to be ActivityStrea.ms (http://www.activitystrea.ms). You should really go through the spec!