# Create a News feed from a database as the source

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a database that I would like to poll and post data from similar to a newsfeed. I have already generated the queries, mysql is the db, to provide the data that I require. What I am not certain about is how to use rails to access the DB and provide updates, based upon 3 minute intervals.

I have worked with tutorials and created the opposite effect, where a user enters a feed and it is posted, along with stored in a database. Being fairly new I am not certain how make the app talk to the db on regular intervals and post it to the site.

To sum it up it would be like this:
Web app polls DB --> Web App looks for specific criteria(like customer name and code) -->Data posted in news feed on web site. -->old news scrolls down the page

Answer (score 1):

You may benefit from reading this question and answers:

[How do I create a facebook style news feed in ruby on rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242173/how-do-i-create-a-facebook-style-news-feed-in-ruby-on-rails)