# Storing reference to generic models in activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to create an activity feed, and I would like to store a reference to the different models that the activities themselves reference. They all have a global parent, lets say for instance "project". But there could be comments, pages, and other models associated to a project that are altered.

So far, I have project_id:integer, user_id:integer, message:text .. but I would like to have a reference back to the original object so that I can dynamically create the url linking back to that object in the activity feed.

Any suggestions?

rails -v 3.2.13 (in the case of some gems or suggestions being for a different version)

I looked at public_activity but wasn't too sure on how to best implement it for the different associations.

Alternatively, I found a post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2247395/319518

What was suggested there is working nicely and gives me greater control and flexibility.

Comment: https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, I found a post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2247395/319518

What was suggested there is working nicely and gives me greater control and flexibility.