# Is there a better acts_as_commentable for Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, facebook, twitter, acts-as-commentable

Here's what I'm looking to do. I have a site where I want the user to be able to leave comments on various Models. acts_as_commentable is the obvious starting point for this, but I'm curious if there is a gem / plug-in with a more robust feature-set. For example:

- Pre-built partial(s) (w/ or w/o Twitter / FB buttons)
- Partial(s) that utilize jQuery
- Twitter and / or FB tunnels (push to the users twitter / FB when they comment)
- Pre-built mechanism for pushing other users comments to users viewing that Model

I can see how some of this functionality could be app specific, however, a generic implementation seems like it would be useful.

I'm curious if something like this exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

I did find this SO post that is similar, however, it is asking more about the approach where I am looking for existing tool(s).

[What's the best manner of implementing a social activity stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202198/whats-the-best-manner-of-implementing-a-social-activity-stream)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find anything that meets your needs.

You could look at [The Ruby Toolbox](http://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_comments.html). Any useful tool shows up on the website.