# Guidance: how to handle exception handling involving tons of observers for an activty stream pattern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, observer-pattern

I'm implementing an ActivityStream for my site based on the answer provided in this question: [What's the best manner of implementing a social activity stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202198/whats-the-best-manner-of-implementing-a-social-activity-stream).

My approach is to use **observers after_create** to create the activity record, including the metadata.  I have a ton of observers, and don't want to write exception handling block for each one.  Is there a way I can use some super observer class to handle the exceptions, with the observer subclasses calling a yield?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure if it applies, but i would create a module with all the shared code (i am guessing a lot of code is similar), and include that in each observer.