# the News Feed technique

Tags: database-design, node.js, feed

I have been read a lot of articles to make a good design for my database so I can get the most recent updates for every single user by executing a - kind of - complex query then I send the data using ajax as a JSON to JS file that makes an appropriate edits for the records. 
It seems fast but I don't know if it will be as much as fast if the site has a large number of users . 
so iv'e started looking for an alternatives . and I found something called **`NodeJS`**  , I really didn't understand what it is stand for and hope that you can help me with that. 
from another hand if the facebook doesn't use a *`normal`* db to do whatever he does , then I think there is no way to do it .
useful link: [What's the best manner of implementing a social activity stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202198/whats-the-best-manner-of-implementing-a-social-activity-stream)
waiting for your comments.
 best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend:

- MongoDB (as db)
- Node.js (for server-side programming)
- nginx (for static content)
- redis (for sessions storing)(optional).

Comment: You can use it instead of MongoDB, but I don't recommend. There is nothing that you can do with SQL and can't with MongoDB.

Comment: Is there any article or other resources that I might find useful for understanding/implementing such a strategy?

Comment: I'm not sure about article with information about all the stack, but there is quite a lot materials about every tool on their sites, such as: mongodb.org, nodejs.org etc.

Comment: @maga "There is nothing that you can do with SQL and can't with MongoDB" -> But there's a lot of what you can do with Mongo but can't with SQL.