# Need to build a news and activity feed for my social network based site any ideas?

Tags: php, database-design, android-activity, social-networking

I need to incorporate a news and updates feed for my site. Basically users can post questions, writes reviews and update profiles etc on the website. I need to set it up so any activity is logged and stored in a database. The thing is that I'm a bit lost on the database structure for setting such a thing up.

How has facebook or like sites implemented their feeds and news?

Comment: It's in Ruby but the Goal is pretty the same - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202198/whats-the-best-manner-of-implementing-a-social-activity-stream There is also a Presentation of how Etsy.com Implemented this at - http://www.slideshare.net/danmckinley/etsy-activity-feeds-architecture Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, I’d like to be open and say that I am an employee of Stream, an API for building scalable news and activity feeds – much like you would see on Facebook, Instagram, and other social media applications.

From my extensive experience as a developer and consultant and continued research and self-education, Stream’s technology stack is extremely effective or competitive. You can get a news or activity feed up and running in a fraction of the time than it would take you to build out your own infrastructure (Cassandra clusters, queuing mechanisms, etc.).

That being said, I highly recommend checking out [Stream](https://getstream.io). What it really comes down to is buy vs build. You can spend months building out a custom solution, or rely on a proven and scalable platform such as Stream that will offer you everything you need to get up and going, in a fraction of the time.

If you're skeptical, check out the 5 minute tutorial at https://getstream.io/get_started/.

Best of luck!